# Why does putting an ImageView on my App makes my system crashed?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

Here is my problem guys! I'm currently trying to develop an Mobile Grocery App. But, when I go to this layout (Baby_Diaper) it crashed? I found the problem here is ImageView, coz when I remove the ImageView it works!

## Baby_Diaper (JAVA)

```
public class Baby_Diaper extends ActionBarActivity {
ArrayList<String> selection = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView final_text;
Button addtoCart;
ImageView diaper_bckgrnd;
Intent i = new Intent(this, Shopping_List.class);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_baby__diaper);
    addtoCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addtocart);
    final_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.final_shopping_diaper);
    diaper_bckgrnd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ctgry_bckgrnd_dpr);

}


public void SelectItem (View view) {

    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view) .isChecked();
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.pampers:

            if(checked)
            {selection.add("Pampers");}
            else
            {
                selection.remove ("Pampers");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.huggies:

            if(checked)
            {selection.add("Huggies");}
            else
            {
                selection.remove ("Huggies");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.johnsons:

            if(checked)
            {selection.add("Johnsons");}
            else
            {
                selection.remove ("Johnsons");
            }

            break;

        case R.id.supreme:

            if(checked)
            {selection.add("Supreme");}
            else
            {
                selection.remove ("Supreme");
            }

            break;
    }
}

public void ocaddtocart(View view){
    String final_shopping_selection = "";

    for (String Selections  : selection){
        final_shopping_selection = final_shopping_selection + Selections + "\n";
    }

    final_text.setText(final_shopping_selection);
    final_text.setEnabled(true);}

public void ocgtshoppinglist (View view){
    Intent x = new Intent(Baby_Diaper.this, Shopping_List.class);
    x.putExtra("items", final_text.getText().toString());

    startActivity(x);
}
```

## Baby_Diaper XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.mobile_grocery.Baby_Diaper"
android:id="@+id/baby_diaper">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ctgry_bckgrnd_dpr"
    android:src="@drawable/category_background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pampers"
    android:id="@+id/pampers"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="SelectItem"
    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/huggies"
    android:id="@+id/huggies"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pampers"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="SelectItem"

    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/johnsons"
    android:id="@+id/johnsons"
    android:layout_below="@+id/huggies"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="SelectItem"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

    />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/supreme"
    android:id="@+id/supreme"
    android:layout_below="@+id/johnsons"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="SelectItem"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/addtocart"
    android:id="@+id/addtocart"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:onClick="ocaddtocart" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Hello Shoppers!"
    android:id="@+id/final_shopping_diaper"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GO TO SHOPPING LIST"
    android:id="@+id/gt_shopping_list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="ocgtshoppinglist"
    />
```

## Logcat Error

```js
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.mobile_grocery/com.example.admin.mobile_grocery.Baby_Diaper}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.admin.mobile_grocery.Baby_Diaper.onCreate(Baby_Diaper.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.admin.mobile_grocery.Baby_Diaper.onCreate(Baby_Diaper.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:636)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:484)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:813)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2277)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:126)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:116)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.example.admin.mobile_grocery.Baby_Diaper.onCreate(Baby_Diaper.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope somebody will lend their knowledge to help me out to this problem.
When I clicked the java in logcat it pointed me here setContentView(R.layout.activity_baby__diaper);

Comment: What is the size (in KB and pixels) of drawable/category_background? and also in which drawable folder is it

Comment: Pixel: 1920 x 1200 ; KB: 269. I just pasted all my Image at drawable. No specific folder

Comment: i think you have a high resolution image, try with a small one

Comment: You drawable dimensions are too big for the memory to load. Please add proper dimension drawable in density specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `OutOfMemoryError`

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

this could be because you are using a very high-resolution image in `ImageView`.
try with a smaller image and check results.

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace shows you're getting OutOfMemory exception.
Your image is large and Hi-res, the solution is simple - 
add the image to drawable-xxhdpi and see if it helps.

Remember that the default base Android density is mdpi, so that caused the OS to do major resizing on an image which was already quite large.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have loaded high resolution image in your layout. 
Please use downscale image instead of your current image.

And if you are not able to solve with that please try below code.

Use below function to down scale your actual image:

```
public static Bitmap scaleImage(String path, int reqHeight, int reqWidth) throws Throwable
{
    Bitmap bitMap = null;
    System.gc();
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists())
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options bitMapFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitMapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), bitMapFactoryOptions);
        bitMapFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bitMapFactoryOptions, reqHeight, reqWidth);
        bitMapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath(), bitMapFactoryOptions);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Throwable(path + " not found or not a valid image");
    }
    return bitMap;
}


private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
        {
            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;
            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth)
            {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

You can also use below function for down scaling your resource image:

```
public static Bitmap scaleImage(Context context, int resourceId, int width, int height, int sampleSize) throws Throwable
    {
        if (resourceId != 0)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // if Sample size 4 then image size (Original-Width/4) X
            // (Original-Heigth/4)
            bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceId, bmpFactoryOptions);
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                // this line convert image size given to width X height
                return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Replace your imageview container in your layout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ctgry_bckgrnd_dpr"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Write below code in your Activity

```
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView diaper_bckgrnd;
diaper_bckgrnd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ctgry_bckgrnd_dpr);

bitmap = scaleImage(context, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_background),500,500,2);
diaper_bckgrnd.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```